# Overriding many functions of class at once with C#

Tags: c#

Maybe overriding isn't the correct term here. 
I want to extend some of the System.Math class functions to work on double arrays.

What I'm currently doing is:

```
public double[] Sin(double[] d)
{
double[] result = new double[d.Length];
for(int i=0;i<result.Length;i++)
     result[i] = Math.Sin(d[i]);
}
```

For many functions in a Math (about 20) just replacing Sin by Cos,Round,...

Is there a way to make this more elegant?

Please note that I'm building something to allow the user to evaluate expressions in runtime.
The user needs to be able to write "Cos(d)" for d double array and for all the functions, so solutions from the input side aren't really an option.

Thanks all

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? `double[] result = d.Select(Math.Sin).ToArray();`

Comment: I didn't know one can do that. That makes things much shorter. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Not really, but you can shorten it with [`Array.ConvertAll`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,f4af030bcf8c8991):

```
double[] result = Array.ConvertAll(d, Math.Sin);
```

If the function name is in a string, you might be able to use a dictionary:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, Func<double[], double[]>> {
    { "Sin", a => Array.ConvertAll(a, Math.Sin) },
    { "Cos", a => Array.ConvertAll(a, Math.Cos) }
};

double[] d = { 1, 2 };
double[] result = dict["Sin"](d);         // { 0.8414709848078965, 0.90929742682568171 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create more generic method to work with the arrays. Something like this

```
internal static void Transform(double[] values, Func<double, double> transformation)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        values[i] = transformation[values[i]];
}
```

Now you can use more concrete methods like

```
internal static void Sin(doube[] values)
{
     return Transform(values, Math.Sin);
}
```

Or

```
 internal static void Cos(doube[] values)
 {
     return Transform(values, Math.Cos);
 }
```

the the usage will be like this

```
var result = Sin(values)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Extension methods:

```
public static class MathExtensions
{
    public static double[] Sin(this double[] input)
    {
        return input.Select(Math.Sin).ToArray();
    }
}
```

And then the call would be:

```
var f = d.Sin();
```

*Note: This doesn't get the syntax you wanted, nor does it solve the issue of having to write one of these for each of the corresponding Math methods but I'll post it here as an answer to how to extend existing methods more elegantly.*

Comment: That's pretty neat! Thanks.

Comment: How would this generalize to a function of 2 inputs? For example Log(number, base) for result = d.Log(base)

Comment: You can add more parameters, no problem, just the first one has the `this` on it.